# Ways of Entering New Vegas

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm generally curious as to how many legitimate ways there are to get into New Vegas at the beginning of the game.

For example, there is the obvious route of

> Entering Freeside and buying a pass/getting one from The King.

However, I was replaying the game, and it seems that I was able to enter The Strip by

> Saving the monorail at Camp McCarran, and then staying on the monorail, which then brought me to the Las Vegas Boulevard Station. I was then able to roam The Strip without ever entering Freeside.

Based on discussions with NPC's, these two routes are presented as the only ways of entering New Vegas.

I am curious to know if this second route was legitimate when I used it so early in the game (and not just a glitch based on my high reputation with the NCR - as I recall from in-game dialogue, the use of this method of transport is reserved for NCR VIP's only, and I believe I was only 'Accepted' by the NCR at the time).

Furthermore, what other legitimate ways (if any) exist to enter The Strip?

Comment: Whether or not something is intended is something only the devs know. All I can say is none of the patches or the 5 DLCs changed it.

Comment: Former QA tester here: We always used the monorail as the fastest way to get to the strip -- it _is_ intended. Don't even need high rep, just an NCR uniform will suffice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are the only two entrances, but there are several ways to get past the securitron's credit check:

- If you have 2000 caps, you pass the credit check and are allowed in. You don't lose the caps (that's what the casinos are for)- the robot just wants to know you're rich enough.
- With 80 Science, you can reprogram the securitron to let you in.
- Ralph will sell a fake passport if you have 50 Speech for 500 caps, or 375 with 50 barter
- If you ask for a way to enter the Strip as your favour from The King, Ralph will give you the passport for free and without the check.
- If you can somehow beat five securitrons, you can fight your way in. The gate is locked but the key can be looted from the securitron who first talks to you. This does give a lot of Strip infamy and turns the other securitrons inside hostile.

The monorail can be used with any positive NCR reputation, or if you disguise yourself as an NCR soldier.

Comment: I blasted my way into the Strip and the Securitrons on the actual Strip didn't seem to care lol They just kept telling me that I better behave and vendors talked me like I was hella sketchy lol